# Deleting markers from a google map help - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to delete all the markers from my map when the user presses a button, which sounds like it should be very simple so i'm probably missing something quite silly.

I have a global array to store them all in:

```
var markersArray = [];
```

I then add all the markers to the map aswell as pushing them onto the array:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: description,
        icon: image,
        shadow: shadow,
        shape: shape
    });

  markersArray.push(marker);
```

And finally i have declared a function that SHOULD delete all the markers from the array:

```
google.maps.Map.prototype.deleteOverlays = function() {
if (markersArray.length) {
    var i;
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work at all however and after countless hours of fiddling with it i'm completely lost. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No errors. Absolutely nothing happens :S

Comment: all right, a seriously dumb question, but still, are you calling deleteOverlays() this way: `google.maps.Map.prototype.deleteOverlays()` - i don't really think so...but since most of the answers are failing, this was what i could think of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array iterator is wrong (and inefficient).
You were iterating through the properties of the array, not the elements.

See the modified code below:

```
google.maps.Map.prototype.deleteOverlays = function() {
if (markersArray.length) {
    for (var i = 0, end = markersArray.length; i < end; i++) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray = new Array(); //like Scorpion-Prince said
  }
}
```

I have done it this way without any problems, and it is also very efficient:

```
clearMarkers = function(){
    var marker;
    while( marker = markers.pop() ){
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have tried your method but it still doesn't work :/
I originally got the iterator from the google maps documentation by the way: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays

Comment: I've edited my answer with the way I'm doing it in a current Google map project I'm working on, where it is working.

Comment: I put together a fiddle to test the efficiency of the different array iterators.  It's obviously not the best way to test, but it should give a good idea of the relative efficiency for each method. http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/me2b3/1/

Comment: Very interesting! I'll have to keep that in mind, its quite a huge difference.
I have tried your clearMarkers function and i still cant get it to work, its so frustrating!

Comment: Try removing `google.maps.Map.prototype.deleteOverlays` and just creating your own function.  The problem is probably the scope.

Comment: @MestekWebmaster - amazing difference! thanks for the fiddle! will keep that in mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the maps.markers to an empty array in after the for loop to clear the markers by adding this line:

```
this.markers = new Array();
```

or

```
this.markers = [];
```

Comment: Just to clarify, where abouts do you mean?
After the for loop thats in the deleteOverlays() function?

Comment: That's correct, after the for loop inside the deleteOverlays() function.

Comment: I have added this and there is no change, it still doesnt work =/

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince actually setting the length to 0 **does** truncate the array. guess what? even i didn't believe that before, but checked it and it did work...that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a standalone page making only changes in the marker options (unknown references). The key part seems to be where the deletion is being called. It has to be able to reference the map variable. `map.deleteOverlays();`

Here is the JS Fiddle and code :

http://jsfiddle.net/VUfEy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var markersArray = [];
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          addMarker(e.latLng);
        });
        document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() { 
          map.deleteOverlays(); 
        };
      }

      function addMarker(latLng) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        //position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        //title: description,
        //icon: image,
        //shadow: shadow,
        //shape: shape
        position: latLng
       });
       markersArray.push(marker);
      }

      google.maps.Map.prototype.deleteOverlays = function() {
       if (markersArray.length) {
        var i;
        for (i in markersArray) {
          markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markersArray.length = 0;
       }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="delete">delete overlays</button>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```